# Postgres shared schema multi-tenant setup for e-commerce SaaS

Tags: mysql, postgresql, multi-tenant, saas

I've researched a lot for the best multi-tenant setup of an e-commerce project but could not find a fitting answer. I am leaning to use a shared database separate schema setup with either MySQL or PostgreSQL. The structure of the tables is the same for all the tenants. I really like that with that setup the application code doesn't need to provide an extra `WHERE` clause for every query, so it is very developer friendly!

Now you also have the shared schema approach and that is what I am currently using, but I feel this is bad for security and isolation purposes. I would like to move to a different solution.

The app will be used by +- 100 webshops (a tenant) this year and I expect it to grow to into the thousands. Webshops ranges from small to large, so it is important that I can later pick out a specific shops data and put it in it's own database server.

Since I don't have any experience with a separate schema setup I would like to know if this would benefit me. What issues might I have when walking that path? Especially with changes in the structure of the tables, this is what bothers me the most. What is the limit of schema's to use in a separate schema approach using PostgreSQL (I will have 100-1000 schemas) before it would be a pain to manage?

Answer (score 1):

The following is my take

> Blockquote

1. When using the SharedDatabase with same table for all tenants, isolation happening with `tenantid` column is easy because you always add a filter that says `tenantid = LoggedInTenantId` [LoggedInTenantId => set during login]. When you have a base method in your ORM like EF [I'm from .Net], this would auto append to any query that goes out of the code.
2. When you opt for shared Schema, if there is a use-case like sharing data between tenants [webshops], it is not feasible. Else, if you have an accountant that wants to audit a collection of tenant's and wants a dashboard to view the a/c statistics etc, it becomes impossible
3. With the scaling point of view, you can better go for a separate db per tenant if a single tenant or a collection of them wants to scale out. This will be better than managing schemas.

Consider the use-cases that you may have for your product and share here so that we can take this discussion forward.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your opinion on this! For dashboard statistics I am using ElasticSearch, so a part of the data (products, order, customers) are also stored there, so it is not impossible for me to gather statistics cross tenants. It is more that I want to know how bad it is to manage a thousand different schema's.

For performance I think separate schema is also much better, since every tenants persistent data will be separated. Not sure how you can achieve such performance too in a shared schema? Also back-ups or moving a tenant to it's own bigger DB seems easier with the separated schema setup.

Comment: Hi @Steffen Brem, please note that I think that the orders tables can scale out to separate databases, with the least changing customer profile from cache, with redis cache, we can achieve the goals with code and allow the cache and scale out of databases to work the default way. Kindly share your ideas on this.